# Activity to allow users to create AND edit a marker on google maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio

Recently, I have been trying to create an application with **android studio** utilising Google Map's API.

**Aim:** 
**The aim is to be able to click on the map, new activity shows up with text fields allowing users to edit the name, snippet, location etc (properties of the marker), and finally create the marker at the point of where they clicked WITH the properties they entered.**

I've been researching for hours however no luck, can't seem to even create a new marker from a separate class.

Map Click Code:

```js
 public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                
                //Coordinates of click
                LatLng new_pos = new LatLng(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude);

                //Needs to be user-editable through an activity or pop up window
                String name = "name";
                String snippet = "snippet";

                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new_pos)
                        .title(name)
                        .snippet(snippet));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(lat, lon)));

            }
```

As you can see above, this is the **click event of the map**, it creates a marker and sets properties to it.

However, i need this marker's properties, such as the name and snippet, to be editable by the user through a textfield upon creation.

Any ideas to how i should approach this issue?

Comment: Perhaps you could forward that information into a set of `EditText`s that display in the same activity? Then the user could make changes to the information, press a button, and update the marker

Comment: That would work however is it possible to do it from another activity? As I'm using a Maps Activity there wouldn't be much room for a set of EditTexts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As both `LatLng` and `MarkerOptions` conveniently implement `Parcelable` you can use the standard Android mecanism to start an `Activity` and return a result from it to add a `Marker` to your map changing it's properties.

**activity_maps.xml** (Trivial, but makes the example complete)

```
<fragment android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="es.jcyl.ita.testmap.MapsActivity"/>
```

**MapsActivity.java**

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private static final int EDIT_REQUEST = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        this.mMap = map;

        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(final LatLng latLng) {
                Intent edit = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, EditActivity.class);
                edit.putExtra("location", latLng);
                MapsActivity.this.startActivityForResult(edit, EDIT_REQUEST);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch(requestCode) {
            case (EDIT_REQUEST) : {
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    MarkerOptions markerOptions = data.getParcelableExtra("marker");
                    mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**editactivity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Title"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**EditActivity.java**

```
public class EditActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.editactivity);

        final LatLng latlng = (LatLng) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("location");

        final EditText title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
        Button boton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
        boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View view) {
                MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(latlng);
                if (title.getText() != null) {
                    marker.title(title.getText().toString());
                }

                Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
                resultIntent.putExtra("marker", marker);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Note: don't forget to add your Activities to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file